# How to target localStorage key for login?

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage

Hello i have tried looking on the thread how to store objects in localStorage and have made the register user with JSON and localStorage and it is working (stores id, username and password) without reseting or overlapping users.

I want to add a login function but I am having trouble looping through the array and targeting the localStorage key? (in this case User:number).

Here is the code:

```
var User = {
    index: window.localStorage.getItem("User:index"),
    $form: document.getElementById("userReg"),


    $button_register: document.getElementById("registerUser"),
    $button_login: document.getElementById("logIN"),

    init: function() {
        // initialize storage index
        if (!User.index) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("User:index", User.index = 1);
        }

        User.$form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
            var entry = {
                id: parseInt(this.id_entry.value),
                user_name: this.user_name.value,
                password: this.password.value
            };
            if (entry.id == 0) {
                User.storeAdd(entry);
            }
        }, true);


        User.$button_login.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

            for (i = 0; i < window.localStorage.length; i++) {}



        }, true);


    },

    storeAdd: function(entry) {
        entry.id = User.index;
        window.localStorage.setItem("User:index", ++User.index);
        window.localStorage.setItem("User:" + entry.id, JSON.stringify(entry));
    },


};



User.init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't rely on the `length` property of `window.localStorage`. localStorage behaves like an Object, not like an Array

In order to iterate through keys of localStorage, do

```
for(var key in window.localStorage){
    var item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
    //do something with item
}
```